# Wordpress Boostrap dropdown menu only works on home page

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having a weird problem with my dropdown menus. They work fine on the homepage but not on any of the other pages.

I cycled all of the plugins on/off with the exception of ACF pro. None of the other plugins had any bearing.

What's even weirder, it all works fine on the dev server. Both sites are on Siteground, running the same plugins and content. I only have 2 templates, one for the home page, one for all of the other pages and they both call the same header.php file.

Here's the dev site: http://rosedental.getthegigs.com/

And here's the live version: http://rosedentalga.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inspect your web page check your console you will find `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` , include `jquery` in your main page, will **Definitely** resolve your issue, and not just drop down your collapsible menu is also not working because of this.
your webpage [image]

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Not sure how I managed to forget the jquery file but seems like that's what happened.

Comment: oh, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are loading jQuery only on the home page. Dropdown menu on Bootstrap needs jQuery. Load jQuery in all the pages and it should be solved.